# Unable to debug my Xamarin app on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am unable to run my Xamarin.Forms app on my Nexus 5X in debug mode. This only started happening recently. If I compile for release I can run it and it works fine on the emulator.

The error I'm seeing is:

```
Java.Lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 

No implementation found for void md5d3ae014f14e8e6870cd0df15a533d422.MainApplication.n_onCreate() 

(tried Java_md5d3ae014f14e8e6870cd0df15a533d422_MainApplication_n_1onCreate and Java_md5d3ae014f14e8e6870cd0df15a533d422_MainApplication_n_1onCreate__)
```

I'm running Xamarin Forms v2.1.0.6525 in Visual Studio 2015.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to clean solution, delete bin and obj folders, restart VS and then rebuild solution?

Comment: Yes I did all those things as well as deleting the app and all data caches from the Nexus.

Comment: Have you tried the next `Forms` point release `V2.1.0.6529`? It states the bug fix: Fix compatibility issue with Android API version 15. Don't know if that applies to you